# Cramer V correlation in python but instead of using frequency using weights?

Tags: python, statistics

So the dataset for Cramer V correlation has multiple categorical variables in columns, but there is also a column that is there telling us how often these values appear. Similar to table below:

```
Season     Age      Weather    Sales
Spring     New      Cold       100
Fall       Old      Warm       50 
Summer     New      Hot        200
```

I want to figure out how to calculate the Cramer V correlation between season/Age/Weather and the weight is sales? If doable how would one write something to calculate it? Or is there a different approach one can take to figure out correlation here? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably know, Cramer's V measures association between **two** nominal variables.  So you can convert your current table into separate contingency tables for each pairwise combination of your variables and then compute pairwise statistics.

Code to create a table similar to yours:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats

np.random.seed(42)

all_combs = product(
    ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter'],
    ['New', 'Old'],
    ['Cold', 'Warm', 'Hot']
)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_combs, columns=['Season', 'Age', 'Weather'])
df['Sales'] = np.random.randint(25, 200, len(df))
df.head()

#     Season    Age    Weather    Sales
# 0   Spring    New      Cold       127
# 1   Spring    New      Warm       117
# 2   Spring    New       Hot        39
# 3   Spring    Old      Cold       131
# 4   Spring    Old      Warm        96
```

Convert the table into a contingency table for measuring association between `Season` and `Age` and save it as 2-d array:

```
cont = df.pivot_table('Sales', 'Season', 'Age', 'sum')
cont
#    Age    New Old
# Season        
# Fall      459 277
# Spring    283 272
# Summer    372 377
# Winter    356 384

cont_arr = cont.values
```

Now, you can calculate the chi-squared statistic and from that compute Cramer's V.  The formula for Cramer's V can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V).

```
chi2 = stats.chi2_contingency(cont_arr, correction=False)[0]
sample_size = np.sum(cont_arr)
min_dim = min(cont_arr.shape) - 1

cramer_v = np.sqrt((chi2 / sample_size) / min_dim)

cramer_v
# 0.1157257...
```

Comment: Thanks I’ll play around with this and see if I can get to do the job but seems like it should work based on what I see! Thx Alex!